# How to log a certain part of a cookie in JS

Tags: node.js, request, http-headers, request-headers, response-headers

I have a response header of `set-cookie` with the value of `set-cookie: frontend=2j5mfe8nidhhmltlaoliu5bmj6; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-2020 22:52:25 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; domain=www.shoepalace.com; httponly` and I want to log just the part of the cookie after `frontend=` up to the `;` (That would be `2j5mfe8nidhhmltlaoliu5bmj6`)

```
const string = response.headers['set-cookie']

            console.log(string) 
    That logs this: 
    [

  'frontend=0uhi7fj03fro4f5n2at4ev1t77; expires=Fri, 11-Sep-2020 01:15:47 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; domain=www.shoepalace.com; HttpOnly',
  '__cf_bm=2d7abb53a603ff50426362615a2cba7c3bd0d58c-1599700547-1800-AVURmHeYokYbppItftnydR/xiAuOS75aQzUlJoxN/79VKKgYr9d7cx6DmgdSK4BbvjQ/pjC0+5lQXkLdn/QIdII=; path=/; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-20 01:45:47 GMT; domain=.shoepalace.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
]


            const pairs = string.split(';')
            const obj = {}

            pairs.forEach(pair => {
                const split = pair.split('=')
                const key = split[0]
                const value = split[1]
                obj[key] = value
            })
              
            console.log(obj.frontend)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const cookies = [
  'frontend=0uhi7fj03fro4f5n2at4ev1t77; expires=Fri, 11-Sep-2020 01:15:47 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; domain=www.shoepalace.com; HttpOnly',
  '__cf_bm=2d7abb53a603ff50426362615a2cba7c3bd0d58c-1599700547-1800-AVURmHeYokYbppItftnydR/xiAuOS75aQzUlJoxN/79VKKgYr9d7cx6DmgdSK4BbvjQ/pjC0+5lQXkLdn/QIdII=; path=/; expires=Thu, 10-Sep-20 01:45:47 GMT; domain=.shoepalace.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None'
]

let frontendValue
cookies.forEach(cookie => {
  const pairs = cookie.split(';')  

  pairs.forEach(pair => {
    const split = pair.split('=')
    const key = split[0]
    if (key === 'frontend') {
      frontendValue = split[1]
    }
  })  
})

console.log(frontendValue)
```

1. We split the string into an array after each ;
2. We create a empty object/dictionary/map
3. Loop through all the key-value pairs we got
4. Split again on the =
5. Read the keys and return the value for frontend

Comment: Then I think you're editing the code example or there is some mismatch in the string. I've changed the code example to a snippet, you can run it and see it logs out 2j5mfe8nidhhmltlaoliu5bmj6

Comment: yeah  got it, but now it says split() is not a funciton

Comment: Hehe its a little hard to guess what's wrong, when you change the code :) You gotta show some code or tell me what has changed, since my code is working, then you're editing it, it gives errors and I have no idea what you changed :D

Comment: Here it is:

```
const string = response.headers['set-cookie']

            console.log(string)

            const pairs = string.split(';')
            const obj = {}

            pairs.forEach(pair => {
                const split = pair.split('=')
                const key = split[0]
                const value = split[1]
                obj[key] = value
            })
              
            console.log(obj.frontend)
```

Comment: I edited the code of the main post to show what I have

Comment: You're using old code, there's no string in the updated code in my answer.